# The Google script copy function with PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS option does not work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

In my Google script I want to extend a range of columns and make their column widths identical to an existing set of columns the manual Sheets command to paste only columns widths works fine but the script:

```
copyTo(columnRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS)
```

does not work.  It copies values and formats instead of just column widths.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

```
sheet.getRange('B:B').copyTo(sheet.getRange('C1'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);
```

You also need to specify `transposed` : the third argument to `false` (which probably defaults to true).

SYNTAX: `copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, this does work.  The example I found in "Google Apps Script" did not include the third argument and I erroneously assumed that the default would be false to not carry out the specified action.

Comment: The 'transposed' parameter is not optional, and no default is used. If this parameter is left out (like the example in the docs) the 2nd parameter will be ignored (maybe 'copyTo(destination, options)' is called instead?

I've sent feedback to the docs crew to fix this example.